# Return Object with Properties of A Second Object referenced by ID with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, backend

Example of a class object

```
{
students: [student._ids will go here],
_id: 61a683115340de04b3eb5448,
teacher: '6170936925956a143a98a02e',
title: '1st Social Studies',
}
```

is there a way for Mongoose to, in my case, populate the teacher with `teacher.firstName`, `teacher.lastName`, and `teacher._id` as an object when passing it to the front end? This would be a list of objects from a `.find` if that's significant.

```js
router.route('/').get((req, res, next) => {
  classSchema.find((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("bad class")
      return next(error)
    } else {
      console.log(data)
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: .populate('teacher') returns the whole object, but I want to specifically only send the first and last name

Answer (score 0):

You can use populate with a projection as the second param:

```
  classSchema.find((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("bad class")
      return next(error)
    } else {
      console.log(data)
      res.json(data)
    }
  }, "students title teacher.firstName teacher.lastName")
```

or select:

```
  classSchema.find((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("bad class")
      return next(error)
    } else {
      console.log(data)
      res.json(data)
    }
  }).select("students title teacher.firstName teacher.lastName")
```